# Sound Analysis/Editing in Android

Tags: android, audio, analysis, editing, native-code

I'd like to know how difficult it is to analyze and edit sound in android. My project would be a kind of DJ application.

I think AudioTrack is the most appropriate library, right ? How does the few android DJ apps work to display the spectrum of the sound, apply effect, change the speed, mix ect ... Do they use a more powerful external sound library ?

For the performances issue, is Java fast enough ( or is there a risk of latency )?

And a last question : How does Korg ported its syth to Ipad, Wormux being ported to android, AngryBird works now on Iphone AND android ,ect ... all these apps seem to be ported to any platform without being re-written... how do they do ? It is because they are written in "Native Code" ? Should I consider this option so I can use other sound library ?

Thanks.

Comment: ..."without being rewritten" seems a little unlikely. There definitely be large portions of code that need rewriting.

Comment: Ahhh ok, seems more logical ^^... And so what would you advise me to use if I want to do a dj app on android ? thanks.

Comment: @Trox did you find any library ?

Answer (score 0):

For purposes of editing sound or applying sound effects to a stream you can use class `AudioTrack` in conjuntion with one of `AudioEffect` subclasses of package `android.media.audiofx`, e.g. `Equalizer` etc ....
In order to analyse sound you should most probably apply FFT algorithms to the bytes you retrieve from class `AudioRecord` or some `Reader`.